# how to correctly change the source ip of a ping packet?

Tags: nat

So I have a private network and there is a host with ip = 10.20.111.2
and there is a firewall for this host which has ip = 10.20.111.1
And of course i has external network , host ip =10.10.111.107

So i would like my external host to ping the private host and private host reply. After that, the external host will examine the ping packet and should find the private host has a IP address = 10.10.111.1

And i used the command on the firewall:
-iptables -F
-iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 10.10.111.1

but when i examine the echo from the external machine, the packet from the private network still has source address = 10.20.111.2 ..which means my command doesn't work.

Please help :(...

Comment: 10.10.111.107 is NOT an external IP. It's part of the IP range 10.0.0.0/8 reserved for private use. See http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918 and http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv4-address-space/ipv4-address-space.xml

Comment: @aseq I don't think qwr is implying that it's public IP space, merely that 10.10.111.107 is external relative to the other subnet in question: 10.20.111.n

Comment: Possibly, it's hard to determine considering the way it was phrased.

Comment: Sorry, 10.10.111.0/24 is the external network.
10.20.111.0/24 is the private network.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE --to 10.10.111.1
```